# How can I programmatically delete a line from a Word document using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I have some code to find and replace fields in a word document with values from a dataset.

```
Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();  
foreach (Word.Field mergeField in oWordDoc.Fields)  
{  
   mergeField.Select();  
   oWord.Selection.TypeText( stringValueFromDataSet );  
}
```

In some cases `stringValueFromDataSet` is empty, and in addition to inserting nothing, I want to actually delete the current line.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, your answer works in your case.  However in the general case (where the 
entire line cannot be removed using a backspace) the following can be used:

```
    private static object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the line in which there is a selection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="application">Instance of Application object.</param>
    private void DeleteCurrentSelectionLine(_Application application)
    {
        object wdLine = WdUnits.wdLine;
        object wdCharacter = WdUnits.wdCharacter;
        object wdExtend = WdMovementType.wdExtend;
        object count = 1;

        Selection selection = application.Selection;
        selection.HomeKey(ref wdLine, ref missing);
        selection.MoveDown(ref wdLine, ref count, ref wdExtend);
        selection.Delete(ref wdCharacter, ref missing);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

OK this was ridiculously easy in the end.

`oWord.Selection.TypeBackspace();//remove the field`
`oWord.Selection.TypeBackspace();//remove the line`