# C# - Replace word document string with backspace

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to replace some strings in a word document with other strings. I created a method to do that.

```
public static void ReplaceAll(
    word.Document doc, string searchText, string replaceText)
{
    object missing = Missing.Value;
    word.Find obj = doc.Application.Selection.Find;
    obj.Text = searchText;
    obj.Replacement.Text = replaceText;

    object replaceAll = word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;

    obj.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}

public static void tagReplace(word.Document doc, Dictionary<string, string> tags)
{
    tags.Keys.ToList().ForEach(key => ReplaceAll(doc, key, tags[key]));
}
```

And in my `button_Click` event I got this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> tags = new Dictionary<string, string>();

tags.Add("***company***", "microsoft");
tags.Add("***name***", "bill gates");
tags.Add("***test***", "\b");

tagReplace(doc, tags);
doc.SaveAs2(path + "testdoc.docx");
doc.Close();
app.Quit();
```

The replacement works perfectly. It does what I want it to do.

For the placeholder `***test***` it should insert a backspace so that the line will be deleted. The problem is that `\b` doesn't put a backspace in this line. The line stays empty but it should disappear. I really get stuck on this problem.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

My code looks now like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> tags = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    tags.Add("***company***", "microsoft");
    tags.Add("***name***", "bill gates");
    tags.Add("***test***", @"\b\b");

    tagReplace(doc, tags);
    doc.SaveAs2(path + "testdoc.docx");
    doc.Close();
    app.Quit();
}

public static void ReplaceAll(word.Document doc, string searchText, string replaceText, word.Application app)
{
    if (replaceText == @"\b\b")
    {
        DeleteCurrentSelectionLine(app);
    }

    else
    {
        object missing = Missing.Value;
        word.Find obj = doc.Application.Selection.Find;
        obj.Text = searchText;
        obj.Replacement.Text = replaceText;

        object replaceAll = word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;

        obj.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
}

public static void tagReplace(word.Document doc, Dictionary<string, string> tags, word.Application app)
{
    tags.Keys.ToList().ForEach(key => ReplaceAll(doc, key, tags[key], app));
}

public static void DeleteCurrentSelectionLine(word.Application application)
{
    object wdLine = word.WdUnits.wdLine;
    object wdCharacter = word.WdUnits.wdCharacter;
    object wdExtend = word.WdMovementType.wdExtend;
    object count = 1;

    word.Selection selection = application.Selection;
    selection.HomeKey(ref wdLine, ref missing);
    selection.MoveDown(ref wdLine, ref count, ref wdExtend);
    selection.Delete(ref wdCharacter, ref missing);
}
```

Comment: See [How can I programmatically delete a line from a Word document using c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838564/how-can-i-programmatically-delete-a-line-from-a-word-document-using-c). Try two backspaces (`\b\b`), or copypaste the method from the accepted answer, which you can execute when your code encounters the double backspace as replace value.

Comment: Thank you. But how should I replace that `***test***` placeholder with this method? I cannot use `tags.Add("***test***, theMethod())` because I have to replace it using a string...

Comment: You can add `@"\b\b"` instead of `theMethod()` and call `theMethod()` in `ReplaceAll()` when it encounters `\b\b` (if the `\b\b` itself doesn't work!).

Comment: `\b\b` doesn't work. If I call `theMethod()` in `ReplaceAll()` it would always delete the line or not? I think I don't understand you right. Or how do you mean "call `theMethod()` in `ReplaceAll()`?

Comment: `if (replaceText == @"\b\b") { theMethod() }`.

Comment: Okay, it deletes a line. But it deletes the line which is one line above the line which should be deleted. I think it's the right way but I just have this little problem. You know why?

Comment: Can you update the question to show your currrent code?

Comment: Couldn't you find an error or the reason why it deletes the upper line?

Answer (score 0):

After a while I figured it out. The way "CodeCaster" told me was working but not perfectly. I now use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range`. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a9dt54a.aspx

I removed the method `DeleteCurrentSelectionLine()` and added the following to my `ReplaceAll()` method:

```
if (replaceText == @"\b\b")
{
    object start = doc.Sentences[2].Start;
    object end = doc.Sentences[2].End;

    word.Range rng = app.ActiveDocument.Range(start, end);
    rng.Delete(ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

I hope I could help everyone who'll have the same problem :)